# Powershell, paginating output from foreach

Tags: powershell, service, scripting, less-unix

Seems like this should be simple, but powershell is winning another battle with me.  Simply wanting to output the name of all the services running on a system, and their executable path, and pipe that into something I can use to search through it like Less.

So far I have:

```
$services = get-WmiObject -query 'select * from win32_service'
foreach($service in $services){$service.Name $service.Pathname} | less
```

But thats giving me the "An empty pipe element is not allowed." that I seem to have come up alot.  Anyone tell me how to fix this, either by outputting to a file and Ill go through it with vim, or pipe to page/less/etc so I can do quick scan (with my eyes not programically quite yet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing the following

```
$services | %{ $_.Pathname } | less
```

**EDIT** Add multiple to the path

```
$services | %{ "{0} {1}" -f $_.Pathname,$_.Name } | less
```

Comment: Good start, editing my intial question to add the $service.Name as well, and that doesnt work with your solution. Any way to add multiple things into the %{} construct?

Comment: Do you happen to know if Pathname is guaranteed to be unique on a given host or can more than one service have the same pathname?

Comment: @WoogyBoogyBoo updated to put multiple things down the paths as a single string

Answer (score 3):

If you are using PowerShell 2.0, you might like this:

```
gwmi win32_service | select-object Name,PathName | ogv
```

ogv (Output-GridView) is a new cmdlet in 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

```
get-wmiobject win32_service | select-object name, pathname | more
```

This is also powershell 2.0 and is the close to the comment above.
You were just trying to use a foreach when you didn't need to in this case.

Even with the foreach, you were close to getting an output you could work with. 
A comma in your foreach would have generated a output like a list and you could have used the more command instead of less.

```
$services = get-WmiObject -query 'select * from win32_service'
foreach($service in $services){$service.Name  $service.Pathname} | more
```

Here is another way to write this same statement.

get-WmiObject win32_service | foreach{$*.Name,  $*.Pathname} | more

This is still not the same as my first example, but I wanted to show you how close you were.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a good reason to use foreach-object:

```
$services = get-WmiObject -query 'select * from win32_service'
$services|ForEach-Object {$_|Select-Object Name,Pathname}|less
```

Please excuse me while I oneline it:

```
get-WmiObject -query 'select * from win32_service' |ForEach-Object {$_|Select-Object Name,Pathname}|less
```

foreach-object will return an object to the pipeline based on the input object.

I'm assuming less is an alias of your own making since I don't seem to have it.